# RabbitMQ consumer in Go

Tags: go, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to write a RabbitMQ Consumer in Go. Which is suppose to take the 5 objects at a time from the queue and process them. Moreover, it is suppose to acknowledge if successfully processed else send to the dead-letter queue for 5 times and then discard, it should be running infinitely and handling the cancellation event of the consumer. 
I have few questions :

1. Is there any concept of `BasicConsumer` vs `EventingBasicConsumer`  in RabbitMq-go [Reference](http://www.jarloo.com/listening-to-rabbitmq-events/)?
2. What is `Model` in RabbitMQ and is it there in RabbitMq-go?
3. How to send the objects when failed to dead-letter queue and again re-queue them after `ttl`
4. What is the significance of `consumerTag` argument in the `ch.Consume` function in the below code
5. Should we use the `channel.Get()` or `channel.Consume()` for this scenario?

What are the changes i need to make in the below code to meet above requirement. I am asking this because i couldn't find decent documentation of RabbitMq-Go.

```
   func main() {

        consumer()        
    }

    func consumer() {

        objConsumerConn := &rabbitMQConn{queueName: "EventCaptureData", conn: nil}      
        initializeConn(&objConsumerConn.conn)


        ch, err := objConsumerConn.conn.Channel()
        failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
        defer ch.Close()

        msgs, err := ch.Consume(
                objConsumerConn.queueName, // queue
                "demo1",     // consumerTag
                false,   // auto-ack
                false,  // exclusive
                false,  // no-local
                false,  // no-wait
                nil,    // args
        )
        failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

        forever := make(chan bool)

        go func() {
            for d := range msgs {                  
                k := new(EventCaptureData)
                b := bytes.Buffer{}
                b.Write(d.Body)
                dec := gob.NewDecoder(&b)  
                err := dec.Decode(&k)
                d.Ack(true)  

                if err != nil { fmt.Println("failed to fetch the data from consumer", err); }
                    fmt.Println(k)                        
            }
        }()      

        log.Printf(" Waiting for Messages to process. To exit press CTRL+C ")
        <-forever

    }
```

**Edited question:**

I have delayed the processing of the messages as suggested in the links [link1](http://yuserinterface.com/dev/2013/01/08/how-to-schedule-delay-messages-with-rabbitmq-using-a-dead-letter-exchange/) [link2](http://www.kuntalganguly.com/2015/02/delay-or-schedule-message-delivery-with.html). But the problem is messages are getting back to their original queue from dead-lettered queue even after ttl. I am using `RabbitMQ 3.0.0`. Can anyone point out what is the problem?

Comment: Try the amqp package to interact with rabbit, also it has a very decent documentation https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp

Comment: @PerroVerd That's what i am using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any concept of BasicConsumer vs EventingBasicConsumer in
>   RabbitMq-go Reference?

Not exactly, but the `Channel.Get` and `Channel.Consume` calls serve a similar concept. With `Channel.Get` you have a non-blocking call that gets the first message if there's any available, or returns `ok=false`. With `Channel.Consume` the queued messages are delivered to a channel.

> What is Model in RabbitMQ and is it there in RabbitMq-go?

If you're referring to the `IModel` and `Connection.CreateModel` in C# RabbitMQ, that's something from the C# lib, not from RabbitMQ itself. It was just an attempt to abstract away from the RabbitMQ "Channel" terminology, but it never caught on.

> How to send the objects when failed to dead-letter queue and again
>   re-queue them after ttl

Use the [delivery.Nack](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery.Nack) method with `requeue=false`.

> What is the significance of consumerTag argument in the ch.Consume
>   function in the below code

The `ConsumerTag` is just a consumer identifier. It can be used to cancel the channel with [channel.Cancel](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.Cancel), and to identify the consumer responsible for the delivery. All messages delivered with the `channel.Consume` will have the `ConsumerTag` field set.

> Should we use the `channel.Get()` or `channel.Consume()` for this scenario?

I think `channel.Get()` is almost never preferable over `channel.Consume()`. With `channel.Get` you'll be polling the queue and wasting CPU doing nothing, which doesn't make sense in Go.

> What are the changes i need to make in the below code to meet above
>   requirement.

1. Since you're batch processing 5 at a time, you can have a goroutine that receives from the consumer channel and once it gets the 5 deliveries you call another function to process them.
2. To acknowledge or send to the dead-letter queue you'll use the [delivery.Ack](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery.Ack) or [delivery.Nack](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery.Nack) functions. You can use `multiple=true` and call it once for the batch. Once the message goes to the dead letter queue, you have to check the `delivery.Headers["x-death"]` header for how many times its been dead-lettered and call [delivery.Reject](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Delivery.Reject) when its been retried for 5 times already.
3. Use [channel.NotifyCancel](https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.NotifyCancel) to handle the cancellation event.

Comment: Thanking you so much for detailed explanation.

Comment: @Pedro..I am having one problem. If i use d.Ack(true) or d.Ack(false) it is not publishing the messages in dead-lettered-queue. Where as in case of d.Nack(true, false) it publishes. But then after ttl it drops the messages from there. So, what are the values to achieve the same

Comment: @Naresh That's a new RabbitMQ question, unrelated to the Go question here. You should create a new question with that.

Comment: I have created new question. Could you please tell me why it is exhibiting this behaviour `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503804/dead-letterred-messages-not-getting-requeue-to-original-queue-after-ttl`